# Mobile Css not being called correctly in JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

My issue is with the site http://navtant.com/ does not pass googles mobile friendly test. (my mobile css fixes all of these issues)

here is my issue, the page should be calling  "style-mobile.css" but it calls style-100px.css and style-desktop.css along with style.css. the page should resemble its sister site: https://equipmenttrackingsolutions.com/ both pages have the same css folder except the path for NavTant is different and I have already checked the path in the JS that determines the browser multiple times.

**NavTant:**

```
    breakpoints: {
        'global':   { range: '*', href: 'assets/css/style.css' },
        'desktop':  { range: '737-', href: 'assets/css/style-desktop.css', containers: 1200, grid: { gutters: 50 } },
        '1000px':   { range: '737-1200', href: 'assets/css/style-1000px.css', containers: 1000, grid: { gutters: 35 }, viewport: { width: 1080 } },
        'mobile':   { range: '-736', href: 'assets/css/style-mobile.css', containers: '100%!', grid: { collapse: true, gutters: 20 }, viewport: { scalable: false } }
    },
```

**ETS:**

```
    breakpoints: {
        'global':   { range: '*', href: 'css/style.css' },
        'desktop':  { range: '737-', href: 'css/style-desktop.css', containers: 1200, grid: { gutters: 50 } },
        '1000px':   { range: '737-1200', href: 'css/style-1000px.css', containers: 1000, grid: { gutters: 35 }, viewport: { width: 1080 } },
        'mobile':   { range: '-736', href: 'css/style-mobile.css', containers: '100%!', grid: { collapse: true, gutters: 20 }, viewport: { scalable: false } }
    },
```

I have had my senior web designer take a look and he directed me here because he cannot figure out the issue either.

I appreciate all help

Comment: Have you followed the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/common-mistakes/blocked-resources?hl=en-US&utm_source=MFT&utm_campaign=MFT&utm_medium=incoming-link

Comment: Make sure you check out how page looks to google:  https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/googlebot-fetch